# I need a word encompassing the meaning of free from something

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, american-english, british-english, vocabulary

Suppose I have a work to accomplish today, but I am not in the mood to finish it. I need the word to comprehend all these ideas.

The sentence to be put in would be like

"Request to free me from the work that I had been assigned today".

"Request to _ from the work that I had been assigned today"

or "Request _ of work that I had been assigned today"
or something close to this formulation.

Comment: "*relieve* me from the work assigned ...". *relieve*: free someone from (a tiresome responsibility) (ODO).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Release or liberate. Liberate is more ideological, release is more legal or relating to protocol.

Of the two I would choose release:

> I request release from work.

Comment: -1 To be released from something is to be set free. In requesting to be exempt from performing a task, job or duty, *release* is inappropriate. Moreover, you didn't say "the work" but simply *work*, which means "job". Therefore, your employer could interpret your request as asking for *leave*.

Answer (score 1):

Consider **[relieve](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/relieve?)** as in *relieve me of this burden*.

> 1. a. to ease, lighten, or reduce (pain, anxiety, etc.)
>
>    b. to free (a person) from pain, discomfort, anxiety, etc.
>
>    c. to restore (a part of the body, the mind, etc.) to well-being
> 2. a.to lighten the pressure, stress, weight, etc. on (something)
>
>    b. to lighten (pressure, stress, etc.)
> 3. a.to give aid or assistance to   ⇒ to relieve the poor
>
>    b. to bring or send help to   ⇒ to relieve a besieged city
> 4. a. to set free from a burden, obligation, grievance, etc.
>
>    b. to remove (a burden, etc.)
> 5. a.to set free from duty or work by replacing with oneself or another   ⇒ to relieve a nurse
>
>    b. (US, baseball) to serve as a relief pitcher for (another pitcher)

In your constructions, you could use the noun form, **relief** as in *I need relief from this obligation*.

Answer (score 1):

Exempt comes to mind and may be appropriate here.

Exempt: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/exempt_1
I request you to exempt me from the work assigned to me.

Also I think absolve can be used also, though its most common meaning is to free from a responsibility or guilt.See 2 in the link
http://www.thefreedictionary.com/absolve
I absolve you from the work assigned to you.